# Set Android Button to be half the height of another button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

What I would like to accomplish I am sure can be done through code, but I need it (if possible) to be done through the declarative XML. I would like to set one button to be half the height of another button.

I found in the ViewGroup documentation you can reference other components, and it evens says this much:

> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.

I'm not sure how to translate that to what I need, however.

The basic layout of my activity xml is as follows:

> 

< RelativeLayout ... >

```
<LinearLayout ... >

    <fragment ... />

    <LinearLayout ... >

        <ImageButton
            ...
            android:id="@+id/userButton"
            android:layout_height=" *tag_button:layout_height / 2? "
            ... />

        <ImageButton
            ...
            android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:layout_height=" *tag_button:layout_height / 2? "
            ... />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tag_button"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ... />
```

< /RelativeLayout>

> And all I really want is to set both the userButton:layout_height and searchButton:layout_height equal to half of the tag_button:layout_height

Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to put both buttons in a linear layout, you can use layout weight

```
<LinearLayout ... >

    <ImageButton
        ...
        android:id="@+id/userButton"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ... />

    <ImageButton
        ...
        android:id="@+id/searchButton"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to directly reference the width of another element in XML. But you can let the layouts do the work for you.

Comment: To clarify, I need both of the <ImageButton> elements to be half the height of the <Button> located in the enclosing <RelativeLayout>

Comment: Got it, I misunderstood. I don't know of a way to do that in XML, unless you define the heights of the buttons apriori. Note that you the doc you are citing is for ViewGroups but not regular Views.

Comment: Well, the answer may well be that it isn't doable, but I'll hold out on that conclusion until I am certain. Also, thanks for pointing the View/ViewGroup distinction.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the principe of weight like this :

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button android:id="@+id/btnUser"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="1" >

<Button android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="1" >

<Button android:id="@+id/btnTag"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="2" >

</LinearLayout>
```

this way , your buttons ( search and user ) will be half of height of the button tag.

**NB : the notion of weight is available only in `LinearLayout` , so if you have a `RelativeLayout`, try to add a child layout into it of type `LinearLayout` , and then , you can use `android:layout_weight`**

Comment: So, the two items in the RelativeLayout are the top level LinearLayout, which fills the entire screen, and then the tag_button, which floats at the bottom with the two menu buttons essentially on either side, and partially underneath, because the tag_button is round.

Comment: in the example of my code you will have the first button in the first 1/4 of height of screen starting from top, the second one will take the second 1.4 of height of the screen , and the tag button will take 1/2 of the height of the screen .